# Why not all values store in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I want to store form data in "moongodb" with MEAN APPLICATION

When I post values of form through my Angular form or using postman all values  not stores even not creating any space for them.

Here is Course Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const CourseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        degprog:String,
        session:String,
        semester:String,
        c_code:String,
        c_title:String,
        c_hours:String,
        c_goals:String,
        m_quiz:Number,
        m_assign:Number,
        m_lab:Number,
        m_mid:Number,
        m_final:Number,
        m_total:Number,
        c_coprdinator:String,
        c_url:String,
        c_catelog:String,
        c_tbook:String,
        c_reference:String,

        teacher:{
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"teacher",

        }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('course', CourseSchema);
```

This is course controller file

```
const Teacher = require('../models/teacher.model.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Create and Save a new Course


exports.create = async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body.courseCode) {
         return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Note Course Code can not be empty"
        });
    }
    //searching for a teacher to add course

    const teacher = await Teacher.findOne({ _id: req.params.teacherId });
    // Create a Course
    const course = new Course();
    course._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
     course.degprog = req.body. degreeProgram;
     course.session = req.body.session;
    course.semester = req.body.semester;
     course.c_code = req.body.courseCode;
    course.c_title = req.body.courseTitle;
    course.c_hours = req.body.creditHours;
    course.m_quiz = req.body.quiz;
    course.m_assign = req.body.assignment;
    course.c_coprdinator = req.body.courseCoordinator;
    course.c_url = req.body.url;
    course.c_catelog = req.body.courseCatelog;
    course.c_tbook = req.body.textbook;
    course.c_reference = req.body.reference;
    course.c_goals = req.body.goals;
    course.teacher = req.body.teacherId;
    course.m_lab = req.body.lab;
    course.m_mid = req.body.mid;
    course.m_final = req.body.final;
     course.m_total = req.body.total;

    //save course in dataBase and attach to particular teacher 
    await course.save();
    await teacher.courses.push(course._id);
    await teacher.save();
    res.send(course);

};
```

This one is routing file

```
app.post('/teacher/:teacherId/course',  course.create);
```

Only till the "URL" values stores. why the remaining values not saving?

Comment: **Only this data saves in database on successful posting data using Angular reactive forms or postman**

  

      {
     "_id":"5ddd47c1a4de66183cf9ab64",
        "degprog":"MCS",
        "session":"2017-19",
        "semester":"2nd",
        "c_code":"424234",
        "c_title":"SE",
        "c_hours":"4234",
        "m_quiz":77,
        "m_assign":88,
        "c_coprdinator":"88",
        "c_url":"fMu",
        "m_lab":888,
        "__v":0
    }

Comment: [FYI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: @DanStarns What do You Mean ?

Comment: are you using body-parser or express.json() ?

Comment: yes i am using  body-parser in my angular services and also tried with postman

Comment: have you console.log(req.body) ?

Comment: i did not .. where should use ? in controller?

Comment: yes at the top of your route

Comment: yes i did this result i got 

`degreeProgram: 'MCS',
  session: '2017-19',
  semester: '2nd',
  courseTitle: 'SE',
  courseCode: '424234',
  creditHours: '4234',
  pre: 'sksjks',
  quiz: '77',
  midTerm: '88',
  finalTerm: '88',
  assignment: '88',
  lab: '888',
  totalMarks: '88',
  courseCoordinator: '88',
  url: 'fMu',
  currentCatelogDescription: 'ndnnn',
  textBook: 'Muavial',
  referenceMaterial: 'CsInBestWay',
  courseGoals: 'Goal is simple' }`

Comment: why don't you try using, `await Course.create({})` and `await Teacher.findByIdAndUpdate()`

Comment: every thing here  i am receiving  as expected

Comment: Where should use "await Course.create({})"

Comment: i did use findByIdAndUpdate but getting the same result

Comment: i am getting this error in console
`(node:5952) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are d deprecated. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#-findandmodify-`

Comment: Please refrain from adding quote markup to your own material in questions. Quote blocks are for quotes, i.e. material in someone else's voice. This has been removed from your other questions, and if you continue to do it, it puts you at risk of receiving downvotes.

Comment: @halfer  sir i will not use Thanks

Answer (score 0):

incoming req.body values were not matching , i did fix it with guide of @DanStarns after console.log incoming values were not matching with schema therefore values were not storing and not creating any space for them.

**here Is Working solution**

```
const Teacher = require('../models/teacher.model.js');
const Course = require('../models/course.model');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Create and Save a new Course


exports.create = async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body.courseCode) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Note Course Code can not be empty"
        });
    }
    //searching for a teacher to add course
    console.log(req.body);
    const teacher = await Teacher.findOne({ _id: req.params.teacherId });
    // Create a Course
    const course = new Course();
    course._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
     course.degprog = req.body. degreeProgram;
     course.session = req.body.session;
    course.semester = req.body.semester;
     course.c_code = req.body.courseCode;
    course.c_title = req.body.courseTitle;
    course.c_hours = req.body.creditHours;
    course.m_quiz = req.body.quiz;
    course.m_assign = req.body.assignment;
    course.c_coordinator = req.body.courseCoordinator;
    course.c_url = req.body.url;
     course.c_catelog = req.body.currentCatelogDescription;
    course.c_tbook = req.body.textBook;
    course.c_reference = req.body.referenceMaterial;
    course.c_goals = req.body.courseGoals;
    course.teacher = req.body.teacherId;
    course.c_pre = req.body.pre;
     course.m_lab = req.body.lab;
    course.m_mid = req.body.midTerm;
    course.m_final = req.body.finalTerm;
     course.m_total = req.body.totalMarks;

    //save course in dataBase and attach to particular teacher 
    await course.save();
    await teacher.courses.push(course._id);
    await teacher.save();
    res.send(course);

};
```